# "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" is bug?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

In my asp.net page return "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small".

but in toad does well.

this is my oracle procedure and asp.net code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIS.test(res out varchar2)
 IS

BEGIN
   res := 't430intw2sBn0UQx8WWO0FlsYLcLOPaJ:1R3xHpLiQGw12xXintomQc3oXbiJtvmw';
END test;
```

-

```
public String Foo()
        {
            string queryString = "TEST";

            OracleParameter[] parameters = 
                { 
                    new OracleParameter("OUT_CURSOR", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
                };

            return ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, queryString, parameters);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the size of your varchar(2) here:

```
new OracleParameter("OUT_CURSOR", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
```

Something like:

```
new OracleParameter("OUT_CURSOR", OracleDbType.Varchar2,32767, ParameterDirection.Output)
```