# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small. Error at ExecuteReader step

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have the following error which I gave when I try to execute my query:

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or
>   value error: character string buffer too small

The piece of code which throws an exception looks like this:

```
OracleConnection ocnn = (OracleConnection)this.Session.Connection;

using (OracleCommand command = ocnn.CreateCommand())
            {
                string getFieldValuesQuery =
                    "SELECT FIELD_NAME"
                    + "FROM FIELD_VALUES WHERE FIELD_GUID in (select ID from table(f_parse_as_table(:fieldIds)) tab ) "
                    + "AND DOCUMENT_GUID in (select ID from table(f_parse_as_table(:documentIds)) tab ) "
                    + "AND RESOURCE_STATUS != 'DEL' ";

                // value is a string which have 55 characters lenght
                if (value != null)
                {
                    getFieldValuesQuery += "AND TEXT_VALUE in (select ID from table(f_parse_as_table(:valuesIn)) tab ) ";
                }

                command.CommandText = getFieldValuesQuery;
                command.BindByName = true;

                OracleParameter fieldIdParameter = new OracleParameter();
                OracleParameter documentIdParameter = new OracleParameter();
                //OracleParameter valuesInParameter = new OracleParameter();
                OracleParameter valuesInParameter = new OracleParameter("valuesIn", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input);


                    fieldIdParameter.ParameterName = "fieldIds";
                    fieldIdParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
                    fieldIdParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    fieldIdParameter.Value = string.Join(",", fieldIds);

                    documentIdParameter.ParameterName = "documentIds";
                    documentIdParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
                    documentIdParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    documentIdParameter.Value = string.Join(",", documentIds);

                    command.Parameters.Add(fieldIdParameter);
                    command.Parameters.Add(documentIdParameter);

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        //valuesInParameter.ParameterName = "valuesIn";
                        //valuesInParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                        //valuesInParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        valuesInParameter.Value = string.Join(",", value);

                        command.Parameters.Add(value);
                    }

                    returnList = this.ExecuteReader(command);
                }
```

I know that the similar answers were asked here but they didn't help me. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585549/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-i) question I set the length of oracle parameter.

All works fine if the length of `value` is less or equals to 50 characters. I don't know where this limitation appears. It's strange, because my **value** filed has `VARCHAR2` type in the table definition and has the length of 2000 characters.

Error was thrown when the `ExecuteReader` method was called.

Comment: You are calling function in the database called f_parse_as_table().  I'm going to guess this function takes in a VARCHAR2(50), which is why it works when the parameter is less then or equal to 50 characters.

Comment: @unleashed Could you write it as answer. It helped me.

Comment: Copied comment as an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling function in the database called f_parse_as_table(). I'm going to guess this function takes in a VARCHAR2(50), which is why it works when the parameter is less then or equal to 50 characters.