# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small whenever I have an OUT Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I know there's already a few posts on this error (
["ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" is bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585549/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-i)), but I've been through them and I still can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.

I can't seem to call stored procedures with an OUT parameter in C#.

I have this stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp(v_payload OUT VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    v_payload := 'he2';
END;
```

It really is as simple as I can make it. It works in Oracle SQL Developer.

But in my c# code.

```
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("test_sp", con);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v_payload", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767, ParameterDirection.Output));
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

It'll return this error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
> small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect constructor. The constructor you're using is:

```
public OracleParameter(string name, System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType oracleType, 
                       int size, string srcColumn);
```

And it appears `string srcColumn` is implicitly converting `ParameterDirection.Output` to string.

Try this instead:

```
var param = new OracleParameter("v_payload", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: yes, you're right. 

When I went `command.Parameters.Add("v_payload", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;` it worked